# Module is not defined visual composer wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, visual-composer

I am intermediate developer of WordPress.

I am developing a wordpress theme using visual composer plugin.

When I create a blog grid through visual composer builtin blog element this error appears in the console.

> **imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js?ver=4.6.1:7 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined** i see this error on this file imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js?ver=4.6.1:7
>   **vc_grid.min.js?ver=4.11.2.1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined**

When I change the theme it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i faced to same problem on my WP grid page:

```
vc_grid.min.js?ver=4.11.2.1:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

after little investigation i found solution, just load "wp-includes/js/underscore.min.js?ver=1.6.0" this library define

```
var _
```

which require for vc_grid.min.js